# Generate PDF Java spring mvc (without IText)

Tags: java, spring, pdf

I have been working on my own project for the past few months and i have stumbled upon a problem. I need to attach some data from database(in pdf format) to emails i will be sending to clients. I know this could be done using Itext, but for commercial licence they charge around 1300$ for 2500 emails which is insane.

Do you guys know any other library i could use in my application i plan to offer commercially? Any other idea which will help me solve this problem will be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) in the distant past.  Admittedly, I was using it for reading PDF files, but it did a good job and seemed well-designed.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I am probably going to go with PDFBox, since it seems like a really well designed and straight forward library. Unfortunately i can only accept one answer!

Answer (score 2):

First you can try 
[flying saucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/)
Basically it uses an old version of iText which was free ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309946/using-flyingsaucer-library-in-commercial-project-licensing))
Flying Saucer will allow you to render PDF on server-side from an HTML template (CSS 2.1 is supported) - we're using this solution (with mustaches templates) in our project

Another option (valid for Google Chrome) - you can do PDF exporting on client, just calling window.print() and using Chrome "Print to PDF' functionality

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache's FOP library for generating PDF. It is released under Apache 2 licence.

https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/